# Sqlite DISTINCT inconsistant results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am getting very different results just by adding a DISTINCT that shouldn't do anything.

My table has ~10000 rows with unique rowids.

However, when I run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM thetable GROUP BY rowid
```

I only get ~6000 of the rows. What?? Shouldn't every row be distinct since every row has a different row id?

Comment: it means all the columns are the same for those ~4000 rows.rowid will be the same for those rows.

Answer (score 3):

Ahhh - rowid isn't automatically included in the returned rows so a row that is otherwise the same will be marked as duplicate.

The following fix works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rowid, * FROM thetable GROUP BY rowid
```